# When was Tor-independence first used as a condition for base change?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-cohomology

In his book on Grothendieck Duality, Lipman uses Tor-independence as a condition for base change.

Recall that a square of spaces (in Lipmans book qs schemes)
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @>F>> B\\
    @V G V V @VV g V\\
    C @>>f> D
\end{CD}
is called tor-independent if it is cartesian and for $b,c,d$ with $g(b)=f(c)=d$ it is
$$
Tor_p^{\mathcal{O}_{D,d}}(\mathcal{O}_{C,c},\mathcal{O}_{B,b})=0
$$
for all $p>0$.

I do not have a good overview over the literature, but older sources, e.g. for topological spaces Spaltenstein, instead simply assume $g$ to be flat (which clearly implies tor-independence).

My question is, when people started using the slightly more general condition.